# CSV into GeoTIFF (bin bash)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, csv, gdal-translate

I have bunches of .csv.gz file and want to convert into GeoTIFF format.
the csv.gz file contains information as below

Line 1: Date/time
line 2: latitude
line 3: longitude
line 4: col
line 5: row
line 6: the resolution
line 7: scanning rotation
line 8: angular angle
line 9 and below: data

and this the view of the data in CSV format

[image]

I do unzip all the files via the bash script. I try using gdal_translate to convert into GeoTIFF but unsuccessfully.

gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "PREDICTOR=2" ${FNAME}.d ${FNAME}.tif

the error: RT_20180909_000_004.d not recognized as a supported file format.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add your full `gdal_translate` call and tell us how it was unsuccessful.

Comment: You should convert it into a GDAL supported format. I think it is similar to ascii grid format, but there is no rotation in that. A don't understand why you have so many rotations? How can you calculate the position of grid point from these data ?